# Как сделать поиск элементов в массиве по частичному соответствию имени?

Tags: java, массивы, поиск

Как сделать поиск нескольких студентов по частичному соответствию имени, возвращающий массив найденных студентов или пустой массив?

```java
private void run() {
    Student[] students = new Student[3];

    Student student = new Student();
    student.name = "Max";

    student = new Student();
    student.name = "Kiril";

    student = new Student();
    student.name = "Kiril";
}

private Student findStudent(Student[] students, String text) {
    for (Student student : students) {
        if (student.name.contains(text)) {
            return student;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как можно сделать сортировку по возрасту этого же массива ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Student {

    private final String name;
    
    private final Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Student(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + '}';
    }
    
    public static Student[] findStudent(Student[] students, String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(students)
                .filter(student -> student.getName().contains(text))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAge))
                .toArray(Student[]::new);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student[] students = {
            new Student("Max", 20),
            new Student("Kiril", 19),
            new Student("Kiril", 17),
            new Student("Artem", 18)
        };
        
        Student[] result = Student.findStudent(students, "iri");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обойти элементы массива можно с помощью метода [`Arrays.stream(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-). Добавляем отбор по условию [`String.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) и возвращаем отсортированный массив:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student[] students = new Student[]{
            new Student("Иван", 20),
            new Student("Пётр", 24),
            new Student("Сидр", 23),
            new Student("Фёдор", 21),
    };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findStudent(students, "ё")));
    // [{name=Фёдор, age=21}, {name=Пётр, age=24}]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findStudent(students, "с")));
    // [{name=Сидр, age=23}]
}

public static Student[] findStudent(Student[] students, String name) {
    return Arrays.stream(students)
            .filter(student -> student
                    .getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge))
            .toArray(Student[]::new);
}
```

В классе `Student` должен присутствовать *геттер* `getAge` для сортировки по возрасту:

```java
public class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public Student(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{name=" + name + ", age=" + age + '}';
    }
}
```

---

См. [`Как сортировать ArrayList<DataModel>?`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214461/419583)